# File.Delete Not Deleting the File

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to delete a file, but the following code doesn't do that.  It doesn't throw an exception, but the file is still there.  Is that possible?

```
try
{
    File.Delete(@"C:\File.txt");
} 
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

If the file can't be deleted, the exception should print out, but it doesn't.  Should this fail silently (as in the File.Delete method is swallowing any errors)?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the file path is correct?  An exception will not be thrown if the file does not exist.

Comment: What makes you think the file isn't being deleted?

Comment: I will verify if this is the case, but the path looked absolutely correct and the file did exist.

Comment: The file is still there after the delete is run.  But the File.Delete doesn't fail.

Comment: Well, then the code isn't getting executed. Can you write a small program to reproduce the problem? How are you calling this? What is the user that is executing it?

Comment: Is it possible that the user executing the code does not have O/S rights to detect the file ? If the user doesn't have rights to see the file, then File.Delete might just be treating things as though the file didn't exist. Maybe you could add a File.Exists check to verify if the user can at least see the file.

Comment: The user has the rights because it gets deleted on restart.  The problem was that the file didn't exist at the time of deletion.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`File.Delete` does not throw an exception if the specified file does not exist. [Some previous versions of the MSDN documentation incorrectly stated that it did].

```
try 
{ 
    string filename = @"C:\File.txt";
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    { 
        File.Delete(filename);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("File does not exist.");
    } 
}  
catch(Exception e) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(e); 
}
```

Comment: @Mitch » I don't think that's right. From the second sentence of MSDN: "_An exception is not thrown_ if the specified file does not exist." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx

Comment: Interesting, I will have to do a File.Exists before the delete to verify this.  Thanks.

Comment: you are correct; the 3.5 doco is correct. some previous versions were not.

Comment: Seem like that if you don't have the permission to delete the file, File.Delete will not delete the file and will not throw any exception.

Comment: F12 in .NET Core 3.1 still states it throws, and a couple of them...

Comment: I wrote pretty the same code: File.Exists returns true, no exception is thrown, but the file is not deleted. The file is in a network volume mapped on Y:
After the File.Delete call I print the message <filename> deleted. I copy the name from the console and I delete it from an MS-DOS prompt and then the file is really deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Check to see that the file's path is correct.  An exception will not be thrown if the file does not exist.  One common mistake is to confuse a file named `File.txt` with one named `File.txt.txt` if "Hide extensions for known file types" is set in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is that the file is still in use by some background process. Then it does not fail but it does not delete the file.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the file name is correct? The only time it doesn't throw an error is if the file doesn't exist. Stupid question, but do you by any chance have a typo in the file name? Or an error in the path?

Answer (score 0):

Another example could be that the delete request is in a kind of queued state. For example when the file has been locked because it has not yet been closed after being edited by another process. If that is the case you can alter that process to close the file properly or kill the process and the file disappears.